# Appending the arrow image if finding the parent nav item with children.

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am not sure if my short Jquery is correct..I am trying to append the arrow image to the parent upon hover if it has children (in Wordpress). If no children, it shouldn't show arrow. 
see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WcM35/

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('ul.sub-menu').parent().addCss('arrow');
    });
```

So far, no arrow appears on parent li if the parent has children upon hover. 
Please guide me and I will appreciate it if you could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //iterate over the collection
    $('ul.sub-menu').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        //does the current element have children?
        if($this.children().length >0){
         //yes, add the class "arrow"
         $this.parent().addClass('arrow');
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WcM35/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to add the class arrow?

```
$('ul.sub-menu').parent().addClass('arrow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addCss use `toggleClass('arrow')`